# Fitting of multiple input multiple output function with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a function that can be written as following:

```
[y1, y2] = function(x1,x2,a,b)
```

And I have some experimental data, is there any function in MATLAB that can help me in the fitting procedure? The function is non-linear and it is defined in an external file (matlab function). I have some experimental data that, given x1 and x2, provides the outputs y1 and y2. I only have to determine the parameters "a" and "b".

I've tried using the curve fitting app, but it works only for single-output function. Same holds for the "fit" MATLAB function.

Comment: It seems that you could solve your issue with a **Neural Network**. Can you have access to the Deep Learning toolbox ?

Comment: Well, there is no reason why a (non-linear) least square method should not work on data 2D -> 2D. If you formulate it that way, any minimization algorithm would basically do.

Comment: Yes, I can use the Neural Network toolbox... Maybe, that can be a possibility I ignored so far.

For what it concerns the second comment: I know this can be done by hand, my question was about a possible MATLAB function that does it automatically without creating my own numerical procedure. The fitting toolbox does not provide this feature.

Thanks
Y

Comment: For what it's worth, an according residual function is likely to be a two-liner. `fminsearch` does the rest.

Comment: ...and BTW... that's what 'LSQNONLIN' requires anyway.